# вывод HTML внутри IF

Tags: php, html

Как правильно вывести html внутри php

Допустим есть следующий код

```
<?php 
  if($cond){
    $n=$n+1;
    echo "<div>Вывод<div>";
  }  
?>
```

Все хорошо, но, что если кусок html большой и не очень удобно писать его через echo. Как будет грамотнее поступить?

Comment: Подключить файл с этим html через echo

Comment: Есть шаблонизаторы, тут дали пример:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/208152/201100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Старайтесь разделять код PHP и HTML.

```
<?php 
  if($cond){
    $n=$n+1;
?>
<div>
    Текущее значение N=<?php echo $n;?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Это работает везде? Никакие дополнительные настройки для php не требуются?

Comment: это основы из основ. PHP обрабатывает только то, что внутри тегов `<?php php?>`, все остальное отдается браузеру без изменений

Comment: `<?php ?>` конечно, с телефона комменты не правятся :)

Comment: Спасибо, почему-то эти основы прошли мимо меня)